# how to restart Linksys WRT400N router

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Linksys WRT400N router and I need to restart it. How do I restart a WRT400N router?

Comment: There's a reset button on the back...

Answer (score 1):

General procedure for restarting consumer (home) routers

- Give a web-browser the URL of the router's admin pages.

  - log in with the admin id and password
  - select restart or reboot from there
- Press the reset button on the casing (if it has one)
- Unplug power and then plug it back in again.
- <strike>Read the user-guide</strike>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [change the password or reset to factory defaults](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&app=vw&vw=1&login=1&json=1&docid=1e97db4854604b0fb5cc8c0d74491e35_19584.xml) you need to:-

Press and hold the reset button (on the back of the router, near the power socket) for ten seconds.